# Are Japanese counters the same when viewing items online?

Tags: words, counters

As an example, I read three books online, would the counter 冊 still be used?　I know that counters are based on size and shape of physical items, do the same rules apply when reading a book online?

Comment: So are you asking about if you read three e-books?

Comment: yes online books

Comment: whats the counter

Comment: If you believe the e-book is almost equivalent in volume with an ordinary paper book, then yes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> counters are based on size and shape of physical items

I'm not sure what you mean by this, but not really --- I'd say we choose counters based upon what we perceive the object to be.

So, for ebooks (as in Kindle), 冊 is used. When you see an object in immersive VR, corresponding counter for that object in real world is used. (On the other hand, developers of the VR might count them with '個' when they consider them as [object](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) that needs to be rendered, rather than what they represent.)

For e-books, things can get a little complicated. When you read three articles on [wikibooks](https://ja.wikibooks.org), I don't think 冊 is appropriate because they are more like online documents rather than books. Documents that are built to be books, on the other hand (like [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)), I'd use 冊. I feel that PDF documents and EPUB documents are more likely to be considered as books in this sense because of how they are styled.  Anyway, although the exact line between online documents and books can depend on the writers' preferences, I think those meant to be books can be counted with 冊.

(Edit: This is my personal observation, but I feel that the essence of the counter of 冊 is pages [not necessarily in physical form]. E.g. 巻物 are not counted with 冊. Thus some e-books without the concept less likely matches 冊.)